# RestKit: crash when executing an RKMapperOperation in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am trying to accelerate an app by pushing to the background Core Data / RestKit operations that were done in the main thread. 
The following simple mapping operation crashes in the RestKit code:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
NSPredicate *pre = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"keyPath IN %@", objectType];
RKEntityMapping *mapping = (RKEntityMapping *)[[[manager responseDescriptors] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pre].firstObject mapping];
NSDictionary *mappingsDictionary = @{ [NSNull null]: mapping };


RKManagedObjectStore *store = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];
RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource *mappingDataSource = [[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:store.mainQueueManagedObjectContext cache:store.managedObjectCache];


RKMapperOperation *mapperOperation = [[RKMapperOperation alloc] initWithRepresentation:data  mappingsDictionary:mappingsDictionary];
mapperOperation.mappingOperationDataSource = mappingDataSource;


[manager.operationQueue addOperation:mapperOperation];
```

If I execute the operation in the main thread:

```
[mapperOperation execute:&mappingError];
```

everything works fine.

I should add the crash only happens when the mapping involves relationships. I mean it only crashes when the JSON I get includes child objects.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: more details.

Models in scope:

`Users` and `Photos`. `Users` "has many" `Photos`.

Mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping *entityMappingUser = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[entityMappingUser addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                                @"id":              @"userID",
                                                                @"name":            @"name",
                                                                @"surname": @"surname",
                                                                }];
entityMappingUser.identificationAttributes = @[ @"userID" ];


RKEntityMapping *entityMappingPhoto = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[entityMappingPhoto addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                             @"id":             @"photoID",
                                                             @"uri":            @"uri",
                                                             }];
entityMappingPhoto.identificationAttributes = @[ @"photoID" ];


[entityMappingUser addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"photos" toKeyPath:@"photos" withMapping:entityMappingPhoto]];
```

JSON:

```
"users":{"245659":{"name":"john","surname":"smith", "id":245659, "photos":[{"id":28945,"uri":"http://..."}]}}
```

Here is what I am doing:

- When I get the JSON, I async map the users with the code at the beginning of the question
- I am showing these users in a collectionView via a NSFetchedResultsController

I get random crashes, in various places. For instance, I will sometimes get one in RKMappingOperation, l.575 (v20.3):

```
if (attributeMapping.destinationKeyPath) {
            [self.destinationObject setValue:value forKeyPath:attributeMapping.destinationKeyPath]; #EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}
```

Yet, destinationObject looks "fine"

```
<TMUser: 0xb54ad20> (entity: User; id: 0xb545900 <x-coredata:///User/tA94DE417-D68E-4D94-927F-6E2667A3BCFD464> ; data: {
    surname = "smith";
    name =nil;
    photos =     (
    );
})
```

and so do value  ("john") and destinationKeyPath (name).

Comment: Show the situation which crashes. Include the JSON, mapping details and exception message and stack trace.

Comment: @Wain done. But the crashes happen randomly, and not always at the same place... so they are hard to pinpoint. And just to reiterate: this code has been running absolutely fine for a while now. The problems only started to happen when we moved the mapping operations to the background.

Answer (score 1):

You should not execute these operations on a background thread that is different than the thread the managed object context was created on. This will cause instability with the CoreData store, as well as cause crashes with the app. You must be VERY careful with how you access objects using threading. For example, accessing an object that was retrieved from a context that is not part of the current thread will cause a crash.

Be sure to read the `Concurrency with CoreData` documentation provided by Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html

Comment: thanks for this. But my understanding of RestKit is that precisely, it helps abstract these complicated problems. With the code above I am using standard RestKit functions - so I thought it "should work", unless I got it wrong and/or my RestKit setup is broken.

Comment: Even with using RestKit you need to be aware of concurrency issues. The issue here is you are using `store.mainQueueManagedObjectContext` in a background queue. This means you are directly accessing the context that is meant to be run on the main thread only–*not* a background thread. Hence why you are running into issues. You never want to use the main context for a background thread.

Comment: I see. But then I am confused as to how to use RestKit. Can you add a RKMapperOperation to the RKObjectManager operationQueue instead of just executing the operation? The documentation seems to suggest you can: "RKMapperOperation is a non-concurrent operation. Execution will occur synchronously on the calling thread unless the operation is enqueued onto an NSOperationQueue." http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKMapperOperation.html And if you can, which context are you supposed to use? The persistentStoreManagedObjectContext one?

Comment: You should use the main queue or create a data source which creates a new MOC on the thread that it is run on. `non-concurrent` is related to how the operation runs, not where you can run it.

Comment: I am starting to think I am completely confused... but @Wain, when you say "you should use the main queue", is it not what [RKObjectManager sharedManager].operationQueue precisely gives you? Are you saying there is no "built in" way with RestKit to run some mapping operations off the main thread (without having to manage additional MOCs yourself)?

Comment: The manager has its own queue (not main). If you run the full mapping stack, RK creates background thread MOCs for you. If you only run part of the stack then either you run it from the main thread or you have to create the MOC (at the right time so the thread is right).